# App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz at deploying project on heroku server

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku

Django project deploy on heroku server, at the time fetch an error at push a project on heroku.

```
Enumerating objects: 63, done.
Counting objects: 100% (63/63), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (60/60), done.
Writing objects: 100% (63/63), 335.77 KiB | 11.19 MiB/s, done.
Total 63 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to youtube-to-mp3converter.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/youtube-to-mp3converter.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/youtube-to-mp3converter.git'
```

How can solve it.